# How to find previous weeks date?

Tags: date, x++, erp, dynamics-365-operations

The method should retrieve the date in the previous week that corresponds most closely to the specified date.

```
fromdate = prevMth(systemDateGet());
```

need to change the above code so that i could get the date of the previous week instead of previous month with respect to the present date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No function is needed, just use date arithmetic.

```
systemDateGet() - 7
```

This will return the prior week date. This of cause implies you use a calendar with 7 day weeks.

Some additional things you may find useful:

- `wkOfYr(...)`
- `dayOfWk(...)`
- `DateTimeUtil::[VariousFunctionsHere]`

Comment: yes indeed this was the snippet! figured it out eventually but thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In D365FinOps you can also use:

```
HcmDateTimeUtil::calculateDateWithOffset(PeriodUnit::Day,7,false)
```